# Mac using wrong route for first IP of range only?

Tags: vpn, routing

I've got the following route configured on my Macbook:

```
204.141.28/22      192.168.1.1        UGSc           en0
```

But when I check some sample addresses in that route, it appears the first IP address is not correctly routed, but all subsequent addresses are?

FIRST ADDRESS

```
route -n get 204.141.28.0
   route to: 204.141.28.0
destination: default
       mask: default
    gateway: 10.77.208.101
  interface: gpd0
      flags: <UP,GATEWAY,DONE,STATIC,PRCLONING>
 recvpipe  sendpipe  ssthresh  rtt,msec    rttvar  hopcount      mtu     expire
       0         0         0         0         0         0      1400         0
```

NEXT ADDRESS

```
route -n get 204.141.28.1
   route to: 204.141.28.1
destination: 204.141.28.0
       mask: 255.255.252.0
    gateway: 192.168.1.1
  interface: en0
      flags: <UP,GATEWAY,DONE,STATIC,PRCLONING>
 recvpipe  sendpipe  ssthresh  rtt,msec    rttvar  hopcount      mtu     expire
       0         0         0         0         0         0      1500         0
```

Notice the different destination/gateway/route-to/mask values.

I only have a single rule for the range in question, and the .0 address is working fine for other ranges (I have 70+) I've got configured. Anyone know why this might be occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subnets use the first IP address as the "network address", similar to how the last address is the "broadcast" address. `204.141.28/22` is shorthand for `204.141.28.0/22`, making the ".0" address the network address. This is merely an identifier and as far as I know it is not used to send or receive data. That's why you can't get a proper route to it.

Comment: That makes sense but the behaviour appears inconsistent. I have other routing ranges defined and when I try to hit their .0 address they appear. to route as expected:

```
route -n get 69.174.108.0
   route to: 69.174.108.0
destination: 69.174.108.0
       mask: 255.255.252.0
    gateway: 192.168.1.1
  interface: en0
      flags: <UP,GATEWAY,DONE,STATIC,PRCLONING>
 recvpipe  sendpipe  ssthresh  rtt,msec    rttvar  hopcount      mtu     expire
       0         0         0         0         0         0      1500         0
```

Comment: @DavidCorley It could be that address is indeed a valid host address if the network is defined as something like `69.174.0.0/16`. In that network, the network address is `69.174.0.0` but other addresses like `69.174.108.0` are actually valid, usable addresses.